# How to hide tailwind css console warnings

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I am using tailwindcss 3 with Laravel 9 after npm run watch everything works fine but the chrome console show some really annoying warnings .
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GdiA.png)

I am using tailwindcss 3 and I didn't use version 2 colors here is all colors I have used.

```
/* Default colors */
```

```
:root {
    --color-primary: theme("colors.rgb.emerald.900");
    --color-secondary: theme("colors.rgb.slate.200");
    --color-success: theme("colors.rgb.emerald.600");
    --color-info: theme("colors.rgb.cyan.500");
    --color-warning: theme("colors.rgb.yellow.400");
    --color-pending: theme("colors.rgb.amber.500");
    --color-danger: theme("colors.rgb.rose.600");
    --color-light: theme("colors.rgb.slate.100");
    --color-dark: theme("colors.rgb.slate.800");
    --color-slate-50: theme("colors.rgb.slate.50");
    --color-slate-100: theme("colors.rgb.slate.100");
    --color-slate-200: theme("colors.rgb.slate.200");
    --color-slate-300: theme("colors.rgb.slate.300");
    --color-slate-400: theme("colors.rgb.slate.400");
    --color-slate-500: theme("colors.rgb.slate.500");
    --color-slate-600: theme("colors.rgb.slate.600");
    --color-slate-700: theme("colors.rgb.slate.700");
    --color-slate-800: theme("colors.rgb.slate.800");
    --color-slate-900: theme("colors.rgb.slate.900");
}
```

Comment: Well,

you should upgrade your tailwind.config.js file

Comment: check `package.json` to see tailwind version you are using

Comment: thank you for your answer package.json shows  "tailwindcss": "^3.0.12"

Comment: @Lk77 can you be more specific please

Comment: well compare your tailwind.config.js to the official one, i think you have an older config file from tailwind 2.x

Comment: It's a good idea to share the warnings as text, [not a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Screenshots are unsearchable for people that have these warnings.